# how can we test HIVE functions without referencing a table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hive-udf

I wanted to understand the UDF WeekOfYear and how it starts the first week. I had to artifically hit a table and run 
the query . I wanted to not hit the table and compute the values. Secondly can I look at the UDF source code?

```
SELECT weekofyear
('12-31-2013')
from a;
```

Comment: just noticed, data format is not Hive-compatible, it should be `2013-12-31` (yyyy-MM-dd)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need table to test UDF since Hive 0.13.0.

See this Jira: [HIVE-178 SELECT without FROM should assume a one-row table with no columns](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-178)

**Test:**

```
hive> SELECT weekofyear('2013-12-31');
```

**Result:**

```
1
```

The source code (master branch) is here: [UDFWeekOfYear.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFWeekOfYear.java)

Answer (score 1):

If you are Java developer, you can write Junit Test cases and test the UDFs..

you can search the source code of all hive built in functions in **grepcode**.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hive/hive-exec/1.0.0/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFWeekOfYear.java

Answer (score 0):

I don't think executing UDF without hitting the tables is possible in Hive.
Even Hive developers [hit the table](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/ql/src/test/queries/clientpositive/udf_weekofyear.q) in UDF testing.

To make query run faster you can:

1. Create table with only one row and run UDF queries on this table
2. Run Hive in local mode.

Hive source code is located [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/). 
`UDFWeekOfYear` source is [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFWeekOfYear.java).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use any table with at least one row to test functions.
Here is an example using a few custom functions that perform work and output a string result.

**Replace anytable with an actual table.**

SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(ST_Polygon(2,0, 2,3, 3,0), ST_Polygon(1,1, 4,1, 4,4, 1,4))) FROM **anytable** LIMIT 1;

HIVE Resuluts:

OK

POLYGON ((2 1, 2.6666666666666665 1, 2 3, 2 1))

Time taken: 0.191 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive>